# If $\phi(n)$ divides $n-1$, prove that $n$ is a product of distinct prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

If $\phi(n)$ divides $n-1$, prove that $n$ is a product of distinct prime numbers (such as number is also called square-free, as it is divisible by no square greater than $1$).

Comment: By the way, no examples are known where $n$ is not actually a prime number, see [Lehmer's totient problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $\displaystyle n=\prod_ip_i^{e_i}$, then $\displaystyle\phi(n)=\prod_i(p_i-1)p_i^{e_i-1}$

Therefore,
$$
\frac{n-1}{\phi(n)}\prod_ip_i^{e_i-1}(p_i-1)=n-1
$$
If any $e_i\gt1$, then $p_i^{e_i-1}$ divides both $n$ and $n-1$. Contradiction.

Comment: Better say $p_i^{e_i - 1} \mid n$ and $p_i^{e_i - 1} \mid n - 1$, so it must be $e_i = 1$.

Comment: @vonbrand: I added the implied "Contradiction" which makes mine the contrapositive.

Answer (score 9):

Hint: If $p^2\mid n$ then $p\mid\phi(n)$. Can $\phi(n)\mid n-1$ in that case?