# Some questions on Euler's phi function

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, soft-question, totient-function

I was reading *Number Theory* by George E. Andrews (Dover 1994,) problem set 6-1, p. 81.  (I'm not a student; I just find problems like these entertaining like some people enjoy crosswords or Sudoku.)  Question No. 1 is to prove that if $\phi(m)|m-1$ then there is no prime $p$ such that $p^2|m$.  I omit the proof here; it is not that difficult but I mention it because the result is useful for proving question No. 2:

> Prove that if $m$ is not prime and $\phi(m)|m-1$, then $m$ has at least three distinct prime factors.

Suppose $m$ has exactly two distinct prime factors; $m=pq$, and $p<q$. If $p=2$ and $q$ is an odd prime, then $\phi(m)=q-1$ and $m-1=2q-1$ but clearly $q-1\nmid 2q-1$. If $p$ and $q$ are both odd primes, then $p\ge 3$, $q\ge 5$ and
$$1 < \frac{m-1}{\phi(m)}=\frac{pq-1}{(p-1)(q-1)}\le \frac{3\cdot 5 - 1}{(3-1)(5-1)}=\frac{14}{8}<2.$$
In this case, $\phi(m)\nmid m-1$ because the quotient is strictly bounded between $1$ and $2$.  The proof is completed by contradiction.

Question No. 3 is on the same premises to prove that $m$ has at least *four* distinct prime factors.

Please leave questions No. 1 and 3 as "homework" or use a spoiler warning if you must answer them.  What I am really asking is first to comment on and correct my proof above, and second, a soft question, "Where does this line of hypotheses and proofs lead beyond question No. 3?"

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344234/if-phin-divides-n-1-prove-that-n-is-a-product-of-distinct-prime-number); there is no example known such that $m$ has at least three prime factors, and $\phi(m)\mid m-1$. Lehrer showed that such numbers are either prime or have at least $7$ different prime factors.

Comment: Lehmer, not Lehrer (just a typo – Dietrich knows this).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh no. Was it my typo, or the German autocorrect function here changing it to Lehrer (=teacher)? Anyway, thank you. I also know [Gus Lehrer](http://sydney.edu.au/science/people/gustav.lehrer.php), but this doesn't belong here.

Comment: Yes, I know Gus Lehrer, and I know of another mathematician, Tom Lehrer.

Answer (score 1):

I will not answer your questions $1$ and $3$, as you have requested (they are answered at MSE here, in case you want to see it later). The soft question may be answered by a [survey article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1116443716) on [*Lehmer's totient problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem), which says that
$$
\phi(m)\mid m-1
$$
if and only if $m$ is prime. There are numerous results on how many prime divisors such $m$ would have, if $m$ were composite.